# Cease your mourning, here's another riddle for you

Tags: riddle

> Fishy to begin with,
> A little unreasonably rounded off.
> Six faces in the middle,
> But needs to be closed a million times.
> Stumped by this riddle?
> Then get off your computer and go live a little!

This riddle has intentionally been made very cryptic, but there are more than enough clues to find the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The advice given in the riddle is:

> Carpe Diem!

which is

> Latin for "Seize the day".
>
>  The phrase was coined by Horace, although the concept is older, for example when Gilgamesh is told him to *forgo the mourning* for his friend Enkidu and embrace life. The riddle's title alludes to this. Today, the phrase has a broader meaning and is often used to just mean *go live a little* as qwr points out in the comments. The last two lines of the riddle refer to the phrase's modern meaning.

That phrase is made up of:

> **carp**: something fishy, a fish
>  **e**: an irrational or "unreasonable" constant (big thanks to Jon Gordon for this one!)
>  **die**: a six-sided thing to roll
>  **m**: the abbreviation of one million

I haven't got a good explanation for the second line.

Comment: I think this is correct. Maybe `e` is a little rounded letter?

Comment: "e" is the last letter of "a little" - maybe it's unreasonable to round off all but the last letter?

Comment: m oehm you're a badass

Comment: Fantastic. For the second clue, what's a synonym for unreasonable? And can you pick out the clues in the title and the last line?

Comment: Carpe Diem is "go live a little". Diem means day, or "mourning"

Comment: @qwr: you got the last line, but the title line is more direct.

Comment: "Carpe" means "seize", which is a homophone of "cease".

Comment: @qwr: Yes, that's one clue, there's something about mourning too. Read up the history of the phrase.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't bother to explain the meaning of the phrase, bacause I thought it was well known. I've added that to my answer. And thanks for the ideas on the second line. I'm still stumped. I would understand if there were a "carpet" being rounded off to get "carpe", but as for something unreasonable being rounded off, I got nothing.

Comment: @MOehm: Irrational is the synonym you're looking for. I can't make it any easier for you.

Comment: Maybe check out [jon_gordon's](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17425/12109) answer?

Comment: Okay, _e_ is an irrational constant. (I need to catch up on my cryptic crossword skills. I still don't see the need to round anything off, though, because _e_ is the name for the unrounded irrational number, no?)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's something like

> INCUBATE.

*Fishy to begin with,

A little unreasonably rounded off.*

> Fishes have fins; the word FIN rounded off becomes IN. This rounding off is 'unreasonable' because it's unreasonable to expect solvers to find it without even the right first letter!

*Six faces in the middle,*

> A solid with six faces is a CUBE, which we find in the middle of the word.

*But needs to be closed a million times.*

> The final part of the word is ATE. In all the meals you ate in your life, your mouth must have needed to be closed at least a million times!

*Stumped by this riddle?

Then get off your computer and go live a little!*

> Thanks for the advice - I'll go and do that right now ;-)

Comment: +1, Nice attempt. But apart from the deduction of CUBE, everything is quite a stretch. Hint: It's not CUBE that you get from that line.

Comment: @CodeNewbie How about HEX then? I looked for words with HEX in the middle, but couldn't find anything that seemed to match the rest...

Comment: Not HEX. I'm not going to give you any hints regarding it, because it's almost all there. Anything more will just give it away.

Comment: @CodeNewbie Just saw one of your recent answers. I think I now know what the 'six faces' bit means ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment as I have insufficient reputation but...

e is a mathematical constant - an irrational number, in fact.  And because it's irrational, we use an approximation - rounded off.

This explains the second line?

Comment: Very good! I hadn't seen the connection between "unreasonable" and "irrational".